While getting the datasets into the google collab notebook , is there any chance that if the runtime is unexpectedly closed , can datasets be recoverd
Downloading datasets regarding a small ML algorithm project
and if my runtime unexpectedly closes, then the whole time the dataset i was uploading in the google colab notebook disappears which is very annoying , i tried some ways to rectify it , but it didnt work, quite annoying to restart again , please help if anyone knows about this
was trying to close runtime and run it again if there are some changes

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
